# Receiving Data Header over TCP IP Node Red

Tags: tcp, node-red

I am making a program to receive data from a 2D scanner that is sent through the data structure below.
I've done this same program in VBA but now that I migrate to the Node Red and I do not know how to get each data from the sensor data header on the Node Network.

Below is a photo of the sensor manual data header.

data header:
[image: data header]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwjcE.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCTC1.png)

Answer (score 0):

So, basically your question is how to parse/unpack the binary data coming from the sensor to retrieve meaningful information. As it is normal in Node-RED there are two possible paths to follow:  Do it by hand OR use some existing library to help you.

Doing it by hand would require things like: store the binary data into a buffer, using function nodes in Node-RED to slice the buffer into separate pieces (using the protocol structure as your map), eventually escaping characters (if required by the protocol), calculating check-sums, etc.. It is not possible to help you further given the scarce amount of information provided in your post. However you certainly will find a supportive community in [Node-RED forum](https://discourse.nodered.org/), so I encourage you [to go there](https://discourse.nodered.org/) for help.

Another way is by taking advantage of existing libraries. This may slow you down as you need to research libraries, chose one and learn how to use it. I can try to help by providing some links for your reading:

1- Node-RED node has a node to handle binary data (node-red-contrib-binary). I never used it so I can not tell you  if it will offer all the capabilities you need. In general using pre-existing nodes (from Node-RED library) is the faster and safer way to proceed.
https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-binary

2- Additional libraries that could eventually be considered:

https://github.com/bigeasy/packet

https://github.com/substack/node-binary

https://github.com/jDataView/jBinary

https://www.npmjs.com/package/binary-parser-encoder

https://www.npmjs.com/package/protobufjs

Edit: Let´s say you chose to use the npm module binary-parser-encoder. The core of your flow will be a single function node with this code (tested ok with random data):

```
var Packet = global.get('binary_parser');
var buf = msg.payload;

var typea = new Packet()
  .endianess("little")
  .uint16("magic")
  .uint16("packet_type")
  .uint32("packet_size")
  .uint16("header_size")
  .uint16("scan_number")
  .uint16("packet_number")
  .double("timestamp_raw")
  .double("timestamp_syncw")
  .uint32("status_flags")
  .uint32("scan_frequencye")
  .uint16("num_points_scan")
  .uint16("num_points_packet")
  .uint16("first_index")
  .uint32("first_angle")
  .uint32("angular_increment")
  .uint32("iq_input")
  .uint32("iq_overload")
  .double("iq_timestamp_raw")
  .double("iq_timestamp_sync")
  .uint8("header_padding");

msg.payload = typea.parse(buf);
return msg;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. What you are looking for and how can I recommend and see if I can analyze the information. the msg.payload of the tcp request sends the information as shown below. Also follows a print of how I assembled the flow structure. If you have one more tip it will be very welcome.

Comment: I just edited the answer to show you how the function node looks like. If you have issues on how to use the npm module in Node-RED please check the Node-RED forum as there are plenty of posts explaining how to do it. If the binary packet has always a fixed structure (which is apparently the case) then your flow will not be much complex.

Comment: thank you very much for the help, I managed to advance my project and also learn more about the node red. I will continue requesting help in the node red community. For coinscidence I found an article dealing with the same sensor.